# htaccess, redirect to a page but prevent direct access

Tags: .htaccess

I'm trying to create redirects to have fancy urls, but i'm struggling in preventing the visitors to access the direct file.

For example, i have a folder `pages` which contains all my `.html` pages, and i want to redirect visitors from `www.mysite.com/mypage` to `www.mysite.com/pages/mypage.html` (redirect but still show the fany url version). I already achieved this adding this rule in my `.htaccess`

```
RewriteRule ^mypage /pages/mypage.html [L]
```

This works fine, the real problem if that the visitors are still able to access `www.mysite.com/pages/mypage.html` directly from the browser, and i don't want to allow that. 
I tried a lot of solutions found but nothing seems to do the trick. My ideal solution would be to redirect to a `404` page when the visitor tries to reach this page, but if is not possibile, i can also return a `410 (gone)` status.

I attach here my full `.htaccess`

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /

    RewriteRule ^mypage /pages/mypage.html [L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /index.html [L]
</IfModule>
```

Thanks for your time

Comment: Hi Gumma. I have provided the working solution along with a tester for your question. In case of any issue, do comment or if that solves your problem up vote and accept the answer so that other SO users can benefit from the same.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the **[G] flag** if you wanted to issue 410. The rule is as below

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/pages/? [NC]
RewriteRule .? - [G]

RewriteRule ^mypage /pages/mypage.html [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.html [L]
```

Working example for the same can be found at online htaccess tester [link](https://htaccess.madewithlove.be?share=4fd2045b-9a0b-5baf-a8e0-fff4f54193ea)

and if you wanted to redirect to 404.html under pages directory you can use the below rule

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/pages/? [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) /pages/404.html [L]

RewriteRule ^mypage /pages/mypage.html [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.html [L]
```

Working example for the same can be found at online htaccess tester [link](https://htaccess.madewithlove.be?share=aa26cffb-968e-53ea-ae45-82ff3a973177)

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply, but if i try your first solution and i go in `/mypage`, htaccess is returning the `gone` status, is like, after the redirect, il will look again in the `htaccess` redirecting me in the `gone` status (https://image.ibb.co/bYtQY0/Untitled.png)

Comment: Don't you want /pages to send a 410 gone. By the way it is not a redirect, it is just sending the 410 gone and not sending a redirect header to the browser. If you don't want than you can remove the optional regex from the rewrite rule. ^/pages/? to ^/pages/. You can also test it through the online htaccess tester. Do let me know

Comment: If you see the attached screen (url bar), you can see that when i try to go to `/privacy` page, it return the gone status (as if i'm going to `/pages/privacy`), i do want to send a `410 gone` when the visitors try to access any `/pages/?`, but right now is returning the `410 gone` status from the `/privacy` page itself

Comment: From the screenshot I can infer two things. First is I can see few rewrite rules above also. Second do privacy.html exists under pages folder?

Comment: the rewrite rules above are all commented, is my old not-workng code and the file exists, see the image https://image.ibb.co/deRZRL/Untitled.png

Comment: I understand now. I will post the answer soon